# Understanding the git data model

Tags: git

I have recently started reading [Git Internals](https://github.com/pluralsight/git-internals-pdf) to understand how git works under the hood. There is a diagram in this book showing the Git data model :

[image]

In this figure I cannot understand what is the meaning of those circles around commit and tree objects. Also the meaning of those three lines from tree to blob is not clear to me. I am wondering if anyone could explain to me what those elements mean in git data model.

Comment: A commit can refer to one or more commits, the parent commits. The very first commit in your repository has no parent (refers to 0 other commits), normal single commits has a reference to their immediate parent (refers to 1 other commit), and merges refer to the parents that make up the merge (usually 2 parent commits, but you can do an octopus merge with more than 2). So commits can refer to other commits, hence the circle. Same with trees. A tree is sort of the directory for a single folder, but that folder/tree can contain subfolders/nested trees, hence trees can refer to other trees.

Comment: Yes, and the three lines from `tree` to `blob` show how each tree references multiple blobs.

Comment: The circles could mean `recursive`. A commit can refer to other commits (submodules) and a tree to other trees (subfolders). The three lines could mean a tree refers to blobs.

Comment: @ElpieKay: commits referring to others isn't related to submodules here, it's just parent commits.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Yes, you are right. I realize that if it was a submodule, it should be referred to by a tree instead. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Note that there's a sort of minor technical glitch here (maybe on purpose as a deliberate simplification): tags can refer to trees or blobs, or to annotated tag objects that can refer to any of the four types of internal objects. `HEAD` can also refer directly to a commit rather than just to a branch name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR: Those circles are actually arrows like the rest of the lines, meaning that commits can reference other commits and trees can reference other trees.

---

All of the lines in this diagram denotes references, A can reference B.

So:

- HEAD can reference a branch (truthfully, HEAD can also reference directly a commit and bypass the branch but let's not overcomplicate your situation just yet)
- a branch can reference a specific commit
- a tag can also reference a specific commit
- a commit can reference a tree (the "directory" of the repository snapshot)
- a tree can reference one or more blobs, files in that directory

However, the circles you ask about mean this:

- A commit usually refers to its parent commits

  - The very first commit in your repository has no parents, and thus reference 0 other commits
  - Normal commits that arent merges reference their immediate parent, and thus reference 1 other commit
  - Merge commits reference the two parents that were merged (or more than two if you do an octopus merge, again, don't overcomplicate so ignore this part)
- A tree is like a directory of a single folder and can thus reference

  - The blobs (files) in that single folder
  - Trees that make up subfolders

So that's that those circles mean, commits and trees can reference recursively commits and trees. There might be an arrowhead missing that made it harder to understand, but that's what those circles mean, they're just round arrows really.